# How can I set the indent of theorem, definition, notes etc.?

Tags: indentation

I would like to set the indent of the theorem title.

```
  \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{amsthm}


    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
    \newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{theorem}


    \end{document}
```

For example:
Default,

```
Theorem 0.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
```

I want,

```
    Theorem 0.1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `amsthm` documentation:

[image]

So, create a new theorem style and then define the new theorems after loading it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{thmindent}{3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{\parindent}{\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}    

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\theoremstyle{thmindent}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}    
\end{document}
```